# Why does this bizarre behavior with add-member on built-in types in Powershell happen?

Tags: powershell

Given this:

```
$x = new-object psobject
$x | add-member noteproperty test 'xtest'
$x.test
$x | add-member noteproperty test2 'xtest2'
$x.test2
```

The output is what I'd expect:

```
xtest
xtest2
```

But given this:

```
$y = @{}
$y | add-member noteproperty test 'ytest'
$y.test
$y | add-member noteproperty test2 'ytest2'
$y.test2
```

I simply get:

```
ytest2
```

I'm confused. And if I do this:

```
$y = @{}
$y | add-member noteproperty test 'ytest'
$y | add-member noteproperty test2 'ytest2'
$y.test
$y.test2
```

Then there is no output at all. Running through get-members confirms that the methods are not actually being added.

What's going on here? This has to be something dumb on my end, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC this really has to do with PSObject wrappers which is a key piece of the extended type system in PowerShell 2.0.  When you execute this:

```
$x = new-object psobject
$x | add-member noteproperty test 'xtest'
$x.test
```

It works because the object is already a PSOject so the Add-Member can add the new NoteProperty directly to the PSObject e.g.:

```
$y = @{}
$y | add-member noteproperty test 'ytest'
$y.test
```

This doesn't work because `$y` isn't initially wrapped so when you execute Add-Member, it creates a *new* object that wraps the original hashtable.  You can see this by using Get-Member e.g.:

```
$y | Get-Member
```

You won't see your `test` property.  To get this to work in v2, you have to do this:

```
$y = $y | add-member noteproperty test ytest -passthru
$y.test
ytest
```

FYI, this changes in V3 since it is based on the DLR it modifies the object directly without creating a new wrapper object e.g.:

```
# PowerShell V3 only
16# $y = @{}
17# Add-Member -InputObject $y test ytest
18# $y.test
ytest
```

Comment: Neato. Thanks for the detailed answer as well as the info on Posh 3!

Comment: Actually..backing up a bit.. Why am I seeing different results from the two ytest examples?

Comment: Not entirely sure but I do know that if you force the creation of the psobject wrapper, it behaves correctly from that point on e.g. `$y = @{};$y.psobject` then execute the rest of your example and it works fine.  Perhaps the first Add-Member in your original example creates the psobject wrapper as a side effect and then it works after that.  Anyway, smells like a bug.

Comment: `$y.test` creates the psobject wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to power shell unrolling your list which is empty. If you want to add a property to the list use the inputobject paramater

```
add-member -input $y noteproperty test1 'ytest1'
```

the usage you described in the question would add a member to every item in the list which you can see in this example

```
C:(...)SequenceId>$y = @()
C:(...)SequenceId>$y += New-Object -t psobject
C:(...)SequenceId>$y += New-Object -t psobject
C:(...)SequenceId>$Y | Add-Member -type noteproperty -name hi -value you
C:(...)SequenceId>$Y

hi
--
you
you
```

@Joey raised this issue that I used a array which is directly iterable. To get the OP semantic to do what I said you would have to do the folowing

```
C:(...)SequenceId>$y = @{}
C:(...)SequenceId>$y["one"] = New-Object -t psobject
C:(...)SequenceId>$y["two"] = New-Object -t psobject
C:(...)SequenceId>$Y | Add-Member -type noteproperty -name hi -value you
C:(...)SequenceId>$y

Name                           Value
----                           -----
two
one

C:(...)SequenceId>$Y.values | Add-Member -type noteproperty -name hi -value you
C:(...)SequenceId>$y

Name                           Value
----                           -----
two                            @{hi=you}
one                            @{hi=you}
```

Comment: Note the minor syntax difference. They're using a hash table, not an array. And hash tables aren't iterated at all (you have to use `GetEnumerator()` to do so. E.g. `@{}|%{$_|gm}` will tell you that the hash table itself found its way through the pipeline, not any elements.